# What ActiveRecord query will return all of the records that have all of a given set of has_many relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

How can I run a joins query to find only the records that contain all has_many relationships?

For example:

Products has many Filters and Filters has many Products. (product_filter_sets is the join table for the two many to many relationships.)

I want to run a query to find the products that contain all the filters using filter IDs.

Currently I have this query

```
Product.joins(:product_filter_sets)
  .where(:product_filter_sets => { product_filter_id: [1,2,4,5] } )
```

But this returns all products that contain at least one of the filters. What I want is products that contain all of the filters.

Answer (score 1):

Join products to filters, group by product and select products that appeared as many times in the join as the number of filters you specified:

```
required_filter_ids = [1, 2, 4, 5]
Product
  .joins(:product_filter_sets)
  .where(product_filter_sets: { product_filter_id: required_filter_ids })
  .group('products.id')
  .having("count(*) = #{required_filter_ids.length}")
```